# Using DSL for my text game, map doesn't match up with what I wrote

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a python text-based adventure game. For the map, I used a dsl called `world_dsl` in order to draw the grid for my map. The issue is, since I expanded my grid from 5x5 to 10x10, the player doesn't seem to start on the tile that I have labeled for a start tile. The game still runs, and is winnable, but the map doesn't match up with what I have.

Here's the code for my map:

```
world_dsl = """
    |EN|FG|EN|EN|  |  |VT|  |  |
    |GT|  |  |EN|FG|  |BT|  |  |
    |FG|EN|  |TT|EN|EN|  |  |GT|
    |  |  |FG|EN|  |  |  |  |EN|
    |  |EN|  |  |EN|TT|EN|EN|FG|
    |FG|EN|EN|  |  |EN|  |GT|EN|
    |  |EN|EN|FG|EN|EN|FG|EN|  |
    |FG|EN|FG|EN|ST|EN|EN|FG|EN|
    |  |  |  |SC|FG|EN|TT|  |  |
    |  |GT|EN|EN|EN|  |  |FG|EN|
"""
def is_dsl_valid(dsl):
    if dsl.count("|ST|") != 1:
        return False
    if dsl.count("|VT|") == 0:
        return False
    lines = dsl.splitlines()
    lines = [l for l in lines if l]
    pipe_counts = [line.count("|") for line in lines]
    for count in pipe_counts:
        if count != pipe_counts[0]:
            return False

    return True

tile_type_dict = {"VT": VictoryTile,
                  "EN": EnemyTile,
                  "ST": StartTile,
                  "FG": FindGoldTile,
                  "TT": TraderTile,
                  "SC": SwordChest,
                  "GT": GambleTile, 
                  "BT": BossTile, 
                  #"RC": RandomChest, #Need to create class
                  "  ": None}


world_map = []

start_tile_location = None

def parse_world_dsl():
    if not is_dsl_valid(world_dsl):
        raise SyntaxError("DSL is invalid!")

    dsl_lines = world_dsl.splitlines()
    dsl_lines = [x for x in dsl_lines if x]

    for y, dsl_row in enumerate(dsl_lines):
        row = []
        dsl_cells = dsl_row.split("|")
        dsl_cells = [c for c in dsl_cells if c.strip()]
        for x, dsl_cell in enumerate(dsl_cells):
            tile_type = tile_type_dict[dsl_cell]
            if tile_type == StartTile:
                global start_tile_location
                start_tile_location = x, y
            row.append(tile_type(x, y) if tile_type else None)

        world_map.append(row)

def tile_at(x, y):
    if x < 0 or y < 0:
        return None
    try:
        return world_map[y][x]
    except IndexError:
        return None
```

Expected results should be that the player starts in the `StartTile` or `ST` in the dictionary included, but they don't and I'm not sure why.

EDIT: I realize that the map is currently showing 9x10 in the post. I went back and fixed that and am still having the issue.

Comment: Looks like the map is 10 rows but only 9 columns.

Comment: Oh snap! Nice catch. I'm kinda new at this, so does that make a difference? Theoretically, the map should work no matter where I put the ST tile right?

Comment: Where do you expect the start tile to be? I get 4,7 when I try to run your script after setting values for StartTile, etc.

I also think you may want to define global start_tile_location in parse_world_dsl, or the start_tile_location in your main program will never be set.

Comment: For each row of your map, you are enumerating the non-blank tiles only (due to the `if c.strip()` test).  This effectively pushes everything over so that it is flush left.  That shouldn't affect the `ST` tile, since it's in a full row, but maybe it just looks wrong because all the other rows are at least partially shifted?

Comment: @jasonharper I don't think that's necessarily the case, as when I run the game I should be able to move south, as you see there should be a FG tile. However, it doesn't even give me the option to move south. The main game module takes away the ability to move to a NoneType tile, so I would assume that - however the map is being crafted at runtime - that there is a NoneType. Also, funnily enough when I'm testing a new tile, I usually put it to the west of ```ST``` and I can successfully navigate to it.

Comment: You can't move south because the row below is effectively `|SC|FG|EN|TT|  |  |  |  |  |` - there aren't enough non-blank tiles in that row to place anything directly under the `ST`.

Comment: @jasonharper so theoretically, if I filled every single tile so that there were no blanks, it would give me a map that matches with the gameplay experience?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Spacing is super important, even in DSLs between triple quotes.

Figured it out myself with the help of you guys in the comments there. Figured I'd post an answer just in case anyone else gets this problem like I had. In the following line of code:

```
dsl_cells = [c for c in dsl_cells if c.strip()]
```

I simply removed the `.strip()` from the end of the line. Earlier, without that part in the line the program would throw a Key Error. I didn't know why at first, and I had posted the question on this site previously. I now understand why. Let's look at the world_dsl that I created:

```
world_dsl = """
    |EN|FG|EN|EN|  |  |VT|  |  |
    |GT|  |  |EN|FG|  |BT|  |  |
    |FG|EN|  |TT|EN|EN|  |  |GT|
    |  |  |FG|EN|  |  |  |  |EN|
    |  |EN|  |  |EN|TT|EN|EN|FG|
    |FG|EN|EN|  |  |EN|  |GT|EN|
    |  |EN|EN|FG|EN|EN|FG|EN|  |
    |FG|EN|FG|EN|ST|EN|EN|FG|EN|
    |  |  |  |SC|FG|EN|TT|  |  |
    |  |GT|EN|EN|EN|  |  |FG|EN|
"""
```

For a beginner, this looks like there's no issues. Until I remembered the Python is super finnicky with indents and spacing. The KeyError that I was getting earlier in development which caused me to add `c.strip()` was something like this:

`KeyError '   '`

And I could not for the life of me figure out why I was getting this. Someone had correctly answered the question at the time time to add `c.strip()` to the code in order to strip away any spacing. However, when I did this, it also messed with the map in the way I described in the original problem. As @jasonharper had said in the comments, any empty or `NoneType` tiles were essentially being pushed over to the right, and any named tiles in a row were flush left. So for example, if our map looked like this originally:

```
|EN|EN|FG|  |ST|
|  |EN|FG|EN|EN|
```

It would now look like this in the game:

```
|EN|EN|FG|ST|  |
|EN|FG|EN|EN|  |
```

To resolve the issue with mapping, it comes down to simple spacing/indentation of the `world_dsl`:

```
world_dsl = """
|EN|EN|FG|EN|EN|  |  |VT|  |  |
|EN|GT|  |  |EN|FG|  |BT|  |  |
|EN|FG|EN|  |TT|EN|EN|  |  |GT|
|TT|  |  |FG|EN|  |  |  |  |EN|
|FG|  |EN|  |  |EN|TT|EN|EN|FG|
|EN|FG|EN|EN|  |  |EN|  |GT|EN|
|FG|  |EN|EN|FG|EN|EN|FG|EN|  |
|  |FG|EN|FG|EN|ST|EN|EN|FG|EN|
|  |  |  |  |SC|FG|EN|TT|  |  |
|  |  |GT|EN|EN|EN|  |  |FG|EN|
"""
```

Once again, pesky Python spacing gets the better of me. But, I can tell that I'm getting better here because I figured it out and caught it this time! Regardless, we can ascertain that `c.strip()` did resolve the earlier error by essentially *stripping* away the spaces to the left of where the first pipe (|) started. However, it caused an issue with spacing on the map which would cause all of the `NoneType` tiles to move to the right of any actual named tile.